# How to filter column parameter in Python (Excel)?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm reading an Excel (`.xlsx`) file:

```py
import openpyxl
     
# Define variable to load the dataframe = openpyxl.load_workbook("cluster.xlsx")

# Define variable to read sheet
dataframe1 = dataframe.active

array = []
     
# Iterate the loop to read the cell values
for row in range(0, dataframe1.max_row):
    for col in dataframe1.iter_cols(1, 1):
        element = str(col[row].value)
        array.append(element)
    
print(array)
```

With this simple script I'm simply populating an array in which I insert all the element of the first column of the table.
[image: These are the two columns]

Up to here, there is no problem. Anyway, here is the question:
If I look at the second column of the Excel file, the field PROFILO, has several option that I can select (`RAOO`, `RUTP`, `UTP`, `VAOO`, `VUTP`).
[image]

If I select one of this field, the number of rows will change. For example, selecting only `RAOO`, I will see 10 row, selecting `RAOO` + `RUTP` I will see 25 rows and so on.
How can I say to my program: `"print the first column of the file, selecting the X parameter in the second column of the file"` ?
Side note: you can't simply filter on the column, because you will have this situation for example:

[image]

As you can see, the corrisponding row to the value `RAOO` is ok, but the corrisponding rows to the value `UTP` and `RUTP` are `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

Hi [@LearningC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20089535/learningc) and thanks for your question.

If I understood correctly, you want to filter table rows based on the `PROFILO` column. I would suggest using the [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) library since it offers the functionality you're looking for (and much more).

### Example data

I'll the workflow using this Excel sheet (`users.xlsx`):

[image: Excel sheet]

### Reading the Excel file

If you have `openpyxl` installed, `pandas` can read `.xlsx` files like this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> sheet = pd.read_excel("users.xlsx")
```

By default, [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) reads the first worksheet. The data is returned as a [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) object, which prints nicely:

```
>>> sheet
  Username AccountType
0    Alice        USER
1      Bob       ADMIN
2      Eve        USER
3    Guest       GUEST
```

### Selecting data using the `AccountType` Column

Suppose you want to select all rows where the value of `AccountType` is `USER`:

```
>>> sheet[sheet["AccountType"] == "USER"]
  Username AccountType
0    Alice        USER
2      Eve        USER
```

This is an example of [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

### Selecting multiple values of `AccountType`

With boolean indexing, you can combine multiple conditions:

```
>>> sheet[(sheet["AccountType"] == "USER") | (sheet["AccountType"] == "ADMIN")]
  Username AccountType
0    Alice        USER
1      Bob       ADMIN
2      Eve        USER
```

### Using a filter criterion

The implementation above has a weakness: You have to add a `sheet["AccountType"] == ...` expression for each value you want to include. Alternatively, you can define a filter criterion:

```
>>> criterion = sheet["AccountType"].map(lambda x: x in ["USER", "ADMIN"])
```

This code:

1. Selects the `AccountType` column: `sheet["AccountType"]`
2. Applies a function to each value of the column: `.map(...)`

Here, the function is given as a [lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#small-functions-and-the-lambda-expression). It's equivalent to:

```
def is_user_or_admin(account_type: str) -> bool:
    return account_type in ["USER", "ADMIN"]
```

`criterion` is a [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) object, which represents a single column of the `DataFrame` object:

```
>>> criterion
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: AccountType, dtype: bool
```

Based on this, we can tell that rows 0..2 match the criterion (`AccountType` equals `USER` or `ADMIN`). In order to get the corresponding data, we use the criterion as an index:

```
>>> sheet[criterion]
  Username AccountType
0    Alice        USER
1      Bob       ADMIN
2      Eve        USER
```

### Closing thoughts

The `pandas` library can be quite intimidating because it's very powerful. But you defininitely want to check it out if you're working with Excel-like data on a regular basis.

Comment: please, read my edit if you can "side note:..."

Comment: for first I would need to show the clean table based on a parameter

Comment: Do you want to "filter out invalid rows"? You can do that using `sheet.dropna()`

Comment: No, the problem is (if you see the last picture), that to one specific user are associated 3 parameters (RAOO, VUTP, UTP) but obviously the corrisponding rows to the last two parameters are NaN. That's why I sould visualize the table each time for a single parameter before doing any operation. Doing this way, there will be no NaN rows

Comment: How did you produce the data in the last picture? Is that a pivot table?